# Segmentation fault when using tensorflow with another library, both linked to eigen3

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, tensorflow, include, eigen3

I am currently trying to use Tensorflow's shared library with another stereo vision library inside my program but I get a segmentation fault when I use both at the same time.

I created a shared library for tensorflow, "libtensorflow_cc.so", so that I can use TensorFlow in other programs using CMake. I can compile a simple tensorflow program using it and run it: the neural network is working fine, I reproduced results I got with Python. TensorFlow (r0.12) is compiled with Protobuf (3.1.0) and Eigen (v3).

I can compile my stereo vision program with the dedicated stereo-vision shared library and run it without TensorFlow.

However, when I include Tenserflow like this:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/core/refcount.h"
```

in the previous stereo-vision program, without using anything else from TensorFlow, I can recompile but I get a segmentation error at run time.

The stereo-vision dedicated shared library includes eigen3. TensorFlow has its own version of eigen3 that uses some functions of the original eigen3.

Therefore, I think that the definitions included by TensorFlow replace the original definitions used when including eigen3. When the dedicated stereo-vision library uses the eigen3 definitions from TensorFlow, it crashes. I ran Valgrind on the program to see this:

```
==10038== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==10038== General Protection Fault
==10038== at 0x7E66E2D: Eigen::ColPivHouseholderQR >::computeInPlace() (in /home/hammouche/.cache/bazel/_bazel_hammouche/0355a6c384eef63f75e9b7278f4fc05b/execroot/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so)
==10038== by 0x1108C490: Eigen::LevenbergMarquardt, double>::minimizeOneStep(Eigen::Matrix&) (in /usr/local/zed/lib/libsl_calibration.so)
```

The function `Eigen::LevenbergMarquardt` in the stereo-vision library (`/usr/local/zed/lib/libsl_calibration.so`) is using definitions from the eigen of TensorFlow (`/home/hammouche/.cache/bazel/_bazel_hammouche/0355a6c384eef63f75e9b7278f4fc05b/execroot/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so`) while it should use definitions from the eigen installed on the computer (`/usr/local/include/eigen3`).

How can I fix this ? Thank you very much in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your `cmake` procedure is exporting Eigen symbols, whereas it shouldn't.

Building with bazel makes sure those symbols are not exported using `exported_symbols_list` directive. I'm not sure what the equivalent command is in cmake. See [Limit the exported symbols from _pywrap_tensorflow.so](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7380) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow uses its own copy of eigen3 which may be different than the one you need in your project.